# Integrating non www to www in an already working web.config for 404

Tags: redirect, web, web-config, http-status-code-404, no-www

After looking for the answer for hours, I need to ask. Let's say I have this `web.config` file that successfully redirects my 404 error page on my windows 2008 server:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument enabled="true">
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="index.aspx" />
                <add value="index.asp" />
                <add value="index.htm" />
                <add value="index.html" />
                <add value="home.aspx" />
                <add value="home.asp" />
                <add value="home.htm" />
                <add value="home.html" />
                <add value="default.aspx" />
                <add value="default.asp" />
                <add value="default.htm" />
                <add value="default.html" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <basicAuthentication enabled="true" />
            </authentication>
        </security>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
            <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
            <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/404.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        </httpErrors>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I want to change the path that does not start with `www` to start with `www` with the xml below. I'm having issues integrating it as it gives me a 500 error (mind you I'm not a very strong developer).

```xml
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect domain.com to www" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domain.com$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.com/{R:0}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I've spent hours looking for an answer without success.